# How to order and make space between items in flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Inside a container, we have 3 boxes (A, B, C). Currently, they all are in floating left positions. But we need them in a position where Box A will be the left, B will be the middle, and C will be the right side of the container. See the image below. How can we achieve this layout? (Please submit your answer with complete CSS. Use .container class name for container and .A .B .C for the boxes)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj4Ca.png)

I fixed this by

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
  order: 1; /* Box A is on the left */
}

.B {
  order: 2; /* Box B is in the middle */
}

.C {
  order: 3; /* Box C is on the right */
}
```

Now I can not solve this.

On mobile layout, we need to swap the positions of these 3 boxes. We need Box C on the left side of the container and the Box A and Box B on the right side of the container. See the image above. How can we achieve this layout?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBq80.png)

I have tried this code

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .A, .B, .C {
        order: 0; /* Reset the order for all boxes */
    }

    .C {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
    }

    .A, .B {
        order: 2; /* Box A right */
    }

    .B {
        order: 3; /* Box B right */
    }
}
```

But I am getting this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v3HL.png)

I am expecting this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBq80.png)

My code here

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
    order: 1; /* Box A right */
}

.B {
    order: 2; /* Box B right */
}

.C {
    order: 3; /* Box C left */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .A, .B, .C {
        order: 0; /* Reset the order for all boxes */
    }

    .C {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
    }

    .A, .B {
        order: 2; /* Box A right */
    }

    .B {
        order: 3; /* Box B right */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box A">
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box B">
    <span>B</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box C">
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the `gap` css property. For example `gap: 2rem` inside your `.container` selector.

Comment: But still there is one item in the middle. That's not what I want to do.

Comment: Hmm can you include your HTML code as I'm not sure I'm correctly understanding the issue

Comment: Edited my question is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, but A and B should be on the right side and C on the left. On my code A comes in the middle. I don't want any box in the middle. Hope you understands.

Comment: Ohh, so you want A and B to be further away from C and not equally spaced?

Comment: Yes, but HTML code should not be changed.

Comment: Is the extra spacing some particular value? Or does C just have to look further away?

Comment: I added a reference image on my question. Can you please check? And this the challenge that I mentioned in my question "On mobile layout, we need to swap the positions of these 3 boxes. We need Box C on the left side of the container and the Box A and Box B on the right side of the container. See the image above. How can we achieve this layout?"

Comment: Yes, i have checked the image but the nature of the dynamic layout has not been clarified. Check my answer to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
    order: 1; /* Box A right */
}

.B {
    order: 2; /* Box B right */
}

.C {
    order: 3; /* Box C left */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .container{
      gap: 25px;
    }

    .A, .B, .C {
        order: 0; /* Reset the order for all boxes */
    }

    .C {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
    }

    .A, .B {
        order: 2; /* Box A right */
    }

    .B {
        order: 3; /* Box B right */
    }
    
    .A {
         margin-left: auto;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box A">
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box B">
    <span>B</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box C">
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the HTML at all, I would add a `margin-right` to `.C` inside of the CSS media query. That way the other two boxes are pushed right:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: .25rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
    order: 1; /* Box A right */
}

.B {
    order: 2; /* Box B right */
}

.C {
    order: 3; /* Box C left */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .A, .B, .C {
        order: 0; /* Reset the order for all boxes */
    }

    .C {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .A, .B {
        order: 2; /* Box A right */
    }

    .B {
        order: 3; /* Box B right */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box A">
    <span>A</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box B">
    <span>B</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box C">
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can play with the `margin-right` value (here it is `auto`, you can set it to eg `30%`) and find the optimal spacing. But `auto` should do the best job;

However if you can change the HTML just a little bit, you could place the boxes inside of their own wrappers, and change the width of the wrapper of C to make it push the other boxes away. Making it take up 50% of the width would make the other two boxes be pushed to the other half of the screen:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.wrapper {
  outline: 2px solid hotpink;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.A {
    order: 1; /* Box A right */
}

.B {
    order: 2; /* Box B right */
}

.C {
    order: 3; /* Box C left */
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .wrapper.a, .wrapper.b, .wrapper.c {
        order: 0; /* Reset the order for all boxes */
    }
  
  .wrapper.c {
      width: calc(50% - 4px);
    }

    .wrapper.c {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
    }

    .wrapper.a, .wrapper.b {
        order: 2; /* Box A right */
    }

    .wrapper.b {
        order: 3; /* Box B right */
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="wrapper a">
    <div class="box A">
      <span>A</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper b">
    <div class="box B">
      <span>B</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="wrapper c">
    <div class="box C">
      <span>C</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can remove the outline of `.wrapper` as it is for testing purposes.

Comment: I think that the one. Thank a lot man.

Comment: We can't predict 30% work in all resolutions with content. See my code for future purpose.

Comment: Yes you are right. I used .C {
        order: 1; /* Box C left */
        margin-right: auto;
    }